# why is $x(\cdot)(x(+)1)$ not backward stable for floating point input?

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra

I am not able to understand this as i have also read an example $1(+) x$ is also not backward stable but still not able to figure it out[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: I will take care about it in future.